# Override a "inherited" JSON property with a specific value

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

Consider the following example schema :

```
"Foo": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "num": {
          "type": "integer",
          "minimum": 1,
          "maximum": 64
        }
  }

"Bla": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "base": {
          "type": "object",
          "allOf" : [
            {"$ref": "#/definitions/Foo"},
            {"num" : {"enum" : [64]} }
          ]
        }
      }
```

What I am trying to achieve is to restrict the value of the inherited property "num" to be only 64 and not just any value between 1 and 64.
Is there a way to achieve this?
For example, I want this to validate :

```
"Bla" : {
"base" : {"num" : 64}
}
```

But not this

```
"Bla" : {
"base" : {"num" : 32}
}
```

Comment: If you wrap the `”num”`  inside the `allOf` in another `properties` you should already achieve what you want.

Comment: Thank you, this worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For completeness' sake providing my earlier comment as answer:

1. If you wrap the `”num”` inside the `allOf` in another `properties` you should already achieve what you want.
2. Additionally, you may want to use `"const": 64` instead of `"enum": [64]` – for its improved readability.
3. If you are free to use the latest Draft 2019-09, you can even avoid the `allOf` since `$ref` is then allowed to be accompanied by other keywords, resulting in something like this:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/schema",

...

  "$defs": {
    "Foo": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "num": {
          "type": "integer",
          "minimum": 1,
          "maximum": 64
        }
      }
    },
    "Bla": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "base": {
          "$ref": "#/$defs/Foo",
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "num": {
              "const" : 64
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You provided me with very valuable info, thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad to hear it. If it answers your question, feel free to accept this answer via the tick mark on the left – thereby avoiding that others unnecessarily spend their time to understand whether a different answer is required.